# RTL8187l Chipset with disconnects and slow speed. please help me

Tags: connection

hi i just installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS
i'm experiencing a few problems with the card. When im using it for internet purposes its very slow and when i try to download a file from the internet, the connection eventually drops and i cannot seem to reconnect to the wifi network.
please help me

Comment: Could you offer more details like the output of `sudo lspci -nnk | grep -A5 Network` and `iwconfig`? Edit your question and add the information asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these commands:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/gkaindl/beaglebone-ubuntu-scripts/master/bb-get-rcn-kernel-source.sh
chmod +x ./bb-get-rcn-kernel-source.sh
./bb-get-rcn-kernel-source.sh
```

OR

go to additional drivers. It will search for additional drivers needed.
If it shows any activated wifi driver, then try removing it and installing it again.
Note: If you remove wifi driver, u need working lan connection to install the wifi driver.

OR
Check this page:
http://www.janoweb.net/tutorials/install-drivers-rtl8187-r8187-rt2800usb-on-ubuntu-lucid-maverick.html#axzz2hOO46W57

OR

May be the distance between the router and your PC is more. If possible, then kindly reduce the distance little bit by moving the router.
Lastly, kindly avoid putting router inside any closed space. Keep it in open space.

Hope this helps.